# How to avoid multiple inheritance using Event filter in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

In my project, I was drawing various shapes like rectangle, polyline, text using QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene.   It works fine. But it has a problem of multiple inheritance. I have derived my SchematicDesign class from multiple classes.

Here is it's .h file :

```
class SchematicDesign : virtual public QGraphicsRectItem, virtual public QGraphicsPathItem, virtual public QGraphicsView
public:
    explicit SchematicDesign();

    explicit SchematicDesign(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height,QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr)
        : QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, width, height, parent)
        {}

    explicit SchematicDesign(QPainterPath pPath);
signals:

public:
    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    QGraphicsRectItem* createRect(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height);
    QGraphicsPathItem* drawPolyline(QPolygonF poly);
    QGraphicsPathItem* addText(QGraphicsRectItem *rect, double d1, double d2, QString s);
};
```

So I was told that, remove multiple inheritance. For that they suggested,

> Use Event filter, it will call event ( only 1 event will be there )
> and in that event, by adjusting various flags, you can draw shapes using
> paint

Now the problem is I did not get this idea completely. I read about Event filter, but question remains that Am I not going to use QGraphicsRectItem or QGraphicsPathItem to draw rectangular or polyline ?
That paint method is QPainter ?
Can anyone help me to understand this ?
A small example will be very helpful

Comment: You'll probably want to read this page if you haven't already done so:  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html

Comment: Do not use inheritance like this. Subclassing means "is a". It makes no sense to say "a SchematicDesign is a rect _and_ a path _and_ a view". It can't be all of these at the same time.

Comment: SchematicDesign should probably just inherit `QGraphicsItem` (or possibly `QGraphicsObject` if you need signals and slots). It may then have a child `QGraphicsRectItem` if you need that.

Comment: @hyde : I understood what you want to say. I want to remove multiple inheritance. But I was suggested to use Event filter for that. I did not get that. How to use Event filter to draw various shapes ?

Comment: @tushar I have no idea why someone would suggest using `eventFilter` to draw different shapes. In general, unless you can answer a question "I am using event filter instead of just subclassing and overriding the virtual protected event methods, because...", you probably should not be using event filter.

Comment: Maybe study this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html

Comment: So do not use multiple inheritance. Split your class into multiple classes and follow single-responsibility rule.